# How to make a proxy for an existing Raknet Application

Tags: java, c#, proxy, netty, raknet

I am currently trying to make a proxy for an application that uses the Raknet protocol. I want to to have the ability to receive the client connection, log/manipulate it and send it to the server, but I'm having difficulties replicating the protocol. I am preferably trying to do this in Java, but I wouldn't mind switching languages if I need to.

I tried using a standard Java socket and a Netty socket, but when I try to immediately forward a connection, it is refused.

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction to replicating the protocol?

I can provide packets I captured from Wireshark if needed.

Comment: Try asking your question at https://www.slikesoft.com/forum/ and see if anyone can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered [this page](https://wiki.vg/Raknet_Protocol), which lists a number of libraries for RakNet, of which I assume some could be used to build a RakNet proxy. That page also has a good description of the different packets that make up the various communication that occurs. It's been really useful for me in conjunction with a packet capture viewed in WireShark (which identifies and decodes RakNet packets).

I also found this project in golang: [Sandertv/go-raknet](https://wiki.vg/Raknet_Protocol), which mentions it could be used to implement a proxy.